# Sockets in Java not working on linux but works on windows

Tags: java

I'm sorry if this question is duplicated, but i didn't find right answer. I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to connect to my Yeelight bubble with socket. Following code is working on windows 10, but not working on Ubunut 20.04. Port is opened, but somehow this don't work on linux, but does on windows.

```
private void sendCommand(String method, String params) {
    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.108", 55443);
        socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {

        out.println("{ \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"" + method + "\", \"params\":[" + params + "]}");
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I always get message: "Receive timed out" and "Read timed out". Does anyone know why this not working on linux?

EDIT:
When i replace `e.getMessage()` with `e.printStackTrace()` i get this:

```
Receive timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326)
at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392)
at com.company.YeeLight.sendCommand(YeeLight.java:105)
at com.company.YeeLight.power(YeeLight.java:85)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Main.java

```
YeeLight yL = new YeeLight();
yL.power("on", 500);
```

Power method in YeeLight class

```
public void power(String power, int duration) {
        this.sendCommand("set_power", "\"" + power + "\", \"smooth\", " + duration);
    }
```

Comment: To better understand the problem, can you do a printStackTrace() rather than getMessage()?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste this in as text. Comments are often unread or deleted by the moderators.

Comment: `socket = new Socket("192.168.1.108", 55443);` That line of your code implies that there is something on the device whose IP address is `192.68.1.108` that is listening to port 55443. Is that the case? Note that you should not assume that it is, you should verify that it is.

Comment: @Abra Yes, I have device on IP 192.168.1.108 and port is 55443 and it works on windows with same values, so I can confirm that values are good. But somehow on linux i can't reach for device. I tried on 2 ubuntu 20.04 devices, one of them have windows in dual boot and works when i boot on windows. I checked ports, ports are opened, but i just somehow can't reach for device on linux.